# Returns unreachable statment inside if statment, i'm returning value but still it says missing return statment

Tags: java

---

> Problem Statment

---

Write a java program to retrieve the player details based on the player id from the array of player objects.

You are provided with the class Player with private attributes such as int playerId, String playerName, int age, long phoneNumber with the necessary setters & getters and a four argument constructor.

Include a class PlayerUtility with the method public Player findPlayerDetailsById(Player[] arr, int playerIdToSearch) that accepts an array of player objects and playerId to be searched as an argument. This method should iterate the array of player objects and find the details of the player for the playerId passed as an argument and return the player object. If the playerId is not found then this method should return null.

In the Main class, you are provided with the main method and the details of the player added into the array.

You need to get the playerId to be searched and call the findPlayerDetailsById method and display the player details as shown in the sample input and output. If the returned value is null, then this method should display “No player found”.

Sample Input 1

Enter the id to be searched

168

Sample Output 1

Name:Christy

Phone number:9856471230

Sample Input 2

Enter the id to be searched

1059

Sample Output 2

No player found

> ***My code***

[Class Player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPUGT.png)

[Continue Player class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G26OR.png)

[class player Utility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqKAZ.png)

[Main class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzg7y.png)

Comment: it most likely means the compiler sees a scenario for which you didn't provide a return statement. show the relevant code (only that method) in your question, don't expect us to go and check a number of classes which aren't even in the question, especially while they're not relevant to your issue

Comment: Please provide ```code``` as text, not images.

Comment: Please provide the code where you are getting that issue, that will you get the answer quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to return outside of for loop in your findPlayerDetailsById method , what if arr parameter is empty? For loop won't iterate if arr.length == 0 so you need to return null after for loop, also you don't need a break statement after return statement, thread leaves the method after return arr[i] so break statement is unreachable